# Finding the target $\lim_{x\to1}(\frac{4x^{101}}{x-1}+\frac{4}{1-x})$

Tags: limits

So I want to solve that limit (why?) so here is my work so far: but professor says it is a false proof... So?

$$\lim_{x\to1}(\frac{4x^{101}}{x-1}+\frac{4}{1-x})=4/0+4/0=\infty$$

i also tried this: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-solve-limits-by-conjugate-multiplication.html

Comment: Note that the denominators differ by sign. It's $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{4(x^{101}-1)}{x-1}.$$

Comment: To answer the parentheses, well, there may be no specific reason for solving that limit other than your teacher wants you to, but limits are used for defining a lot of crazy things!

Comment: Also to answer why it's a false proof, what your saying is that the limit of the sum is the sum of limits. This is ok... in some cases. Do you know which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without l'Hopital's rule (although it is not computationally easier, it may be conceptually easier).

Note that $(x-1)$ is a factor of $(x^n-1)$ for integers $n\ge1$. For example:

$$(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^5-1)$$

$$\therefore 4\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}=4\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac{x^{100}+x^{99}+x^{98}+\cdots+x^2+x+1}{1}$$

There are  101 terms in that second polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Using [l'Hospital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) you get
$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{4x^{101} - 4}{x-1} = 4 \lim_{x\to1} \frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1} \stackrel{\text{l'H}}= 4\lim_{x\to1} \frac{101 x^{100}}1 = 404$$

Comment: I wouldn't bother with L'Hopital - this is the definition of the derivative of $x^{101}$ at $1$.